# How to open a dialog box on the click of a widget button in android

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am trying to create a button in my app's widget. I expect it to open a dialog box when clicked. I am unsure of how to implement this.
Here is the widget's code:

```
public class IncompleteTodosWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, timeTypeSelector.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                /* context = */ context,
                /* requestCode = */ 0,
                /* intent = */ intent,
                /* flags = */ PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        );

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.incomplete_todos_widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent);


        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code of the dialog box:

```
public class timeTypeSelector extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Demo message")
                .setPositiveButton("Perform miracles", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Log.d("Bitcoin has reached 69,42,000");
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Log.d("Bitcoin would have reached 69,42,000 if you had clicked the other button");
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

When I try clicking the view with id appwidget_text, my app gets opened instead of the dialog box. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hej Pro,

a [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent) cannot target a `DialogFragment` directly - only Activity, Service or Broadcast.

You have to set an action on your Intent to identify the click on the view with id (*R.id.appwidget_text*). When your app is opened and check the received Intent if it is the action for displaying your `DialogFragment` and navigate to it.

Comment: Thats a cool idea, the only problem is that my app is written in react native.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with React Native. I think you should add this information to your question and also the "react native"-tag. From the question it reads like a Android native project.